# BizTalk Schedule Task Adapter for Schedule Type "Weekly" Not Triggered

Tags: scheduled-tasks, biztalk

I have v 5.04 of the Codeplex BizTalk schedule task adapter installed (https://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/releases/view/612575)

I'm running BizTalk 2013r2 Standard Edition. I have created a dedicated host instance for the use of the adapter.
I have a couple of receive locations configured to use the adapter, one has "Schedule Type" of the "Schedule" tab set to "TimeSpan" every 2 minutes - this works fine. The other receive location (on a different) receive port is configured with Start Date "17/12/2014", Start Time "10:00 AM" and Schedule Type "Weekly", Weekly Properties "Every 1 weeks", day of week "Monday".

I have message tracking enabled for both receive ports. For some reason, the Weekly schedule task is not being triggered. Any else seen the problem?

Comment: You've probably checked this but, is the receive location enabled?

Comment: Thanks, but yes receive location is enabled

Comment: Presume that nothing is being logged in the application event log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in v5.04 - see here: https://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/releases/view/612575